# C++ Linker error with a function definition outside class

Tags: c++

Its such a weird error with my C++ code.

I want to maintain a header file with some methods. Lets call it `Util.hpp`. I have the below simple method in it.

```
bool CheckVal(int value) {

  if (value == 1)
    return true;
  else
    return false;    
}
```

I include `Util.hpp` in another class's cpp & invoke the method. I end up with a linker error saying

```
:-1: error: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

I am building this with clang on osx.

**How can I get rid of this error ?** **what is so wrong in what I am doing ?**

I am having the error in spite of inlining the function. really strange !

Comment: Make it `inline`.

Comment: make it static. This works for C as well.

Comment: This simple method isn't as simple as it could be.

Comment: _"I am having the error in spite of inlining the function. really strange !"_ Did you define that same function somewhere else?

Comment: Nope. I just inlined it in `Util.hpp`. it doesn't help. trying out other means

Comment: @SegmentationFault Add every information you can give us please. Including your compiler and linker command lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep free function definitions in a header file you must make them with the `inline` keyword:

```
   inline bool CheckVal(int value) {       
// ^^^^^^
      return value == 1;
   }
```

Otherwise the function definition appears in every translation unit that includes the header file, and the linker sees multiple definitions of it.

---

Also as I did above you don't need `if`/`else` for retuning `bool` values.

---

Another solution is to just declare the function in the header

```
bool CheckVal(int value);
```

and move the implementation (definition) to a separate translation unit.
That has at least the advantage that any dependend translation units on that header won't need to be recompiled, if you change something in the implementation.

Comment: inlining is not helping. really strange. any option other than declaring it in cpp file ?

Comment: @SegmentationFault `inline` should work just fine. Did you define that same function anywhere else? Edit your question with a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: I went for the other solution. inlining does not help in my case

Comment: @SegmentationFault It would be very interesting to figure out why `inline` didn't work for your case. Just don't give up too early, give us more context as I advised please.

Answer (score 1):

> what is so wrong in what I am doing ?

The one definition rule requires that a (non inline) function must be defined exactly once<sup>†</sup>.

If you include your header in multiple translation units, then there will be multiple definitions, thus odr is violated.

If there are multiple - different definitions for the function, that also violates odr.

> How can I get rid of this error ?

Solution 1: Do not define the function in a header. Instead define it in a source file. Source files are not included in other source files, so there should be exactly one definition when you use this approach.

Solution A: Declare the function `inline`.

In both cases, check that there are no other functions by the same name.

---

<sup>†</sup> Only if the function is odr-used. This subtlety is not relevant to this question.